# Weird behavior when object moves outside of canvas t-rex

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to modify the t-rex game to make the character dive instead of jump. This is what I'm referring to: https://github.com/xkuga/t-rex-runner.

As soon as the character dives out of the canvas, it leaves an unexpected trail.

I don't expect you to make clone & make changes in the repo to replicate this behavior. I have changed canvas size, the container size, tried clearing up canvas but nothing helped. Can you suggest possible reasons?

[image: t-rex]

Comment: It seems like a clearRect issue to me.  A code example would help some. You have to clear the canvas with each frame, or at least clear the part of the canvas the protagonist moves from.

 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect

Comment: Thanks @JoeFitzsimmons, this was it. Can you please add this as an answer so that I can mark it answered?

Comment: No problem. Added my comment as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a clearRect issue to me. A code example would help some. You have to clear the canvas with each frame, or at least clear the part of the canvas the protagonist moves from.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect